# Java Resolve Relative Path

Tags: java

How would you go about resolving a relative path? What I am looking for is a function similar to php's realpath. The function just needs to remove all ../ ./ so that the input string can be safely used with other strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general way is to use the File class [getCanonicalPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath--) method.
It's specifically documented to remove (resolve) the `../` and `./` that you're looking for.

Extracts from the docs:

> This method first converts this pathname to absolute form if necessary [...] and then maps it to its unique form in a system-dependent way. This typically involves removing redundant names such as **"."** and **".."** from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on Microsoft Windows platforms).

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned PHP, I'll assume a web context. With the Servlet API you can get a real path corresponding to a relative path using `servletContext.getRealPath(relativePath)`

Outside a web context you can use `file.getAbsolutePath()`, where `file` is `java.io.File` constructed with a relative path.

Comment: actually I am looking for a generic function.... there must be something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not in production yet, but in Java 7 one would call [Path.resolve(Path)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

Just a heads-up.

Comment: more-or-less, Path.resolve just does clever joining of two parts of a path. e.g. directory path + file name, plus some other tricks. "this method joins the given path to this path and returns a resulting path that ends with the given path."