# How to get the complete real file path for "../../dir/file.ext" in java?

Tags: java, file, relative-path

I there a way in the java.io package to convert a relative path containing "../" to an absolute path?

My goal is to remove the "../" part of the path because

```
 java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open()
```

Does not seem to support ../ in file path under windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Resolve Relative Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121967/java-resolve-relative-path)

Comment: Hard to imagine that any file path question isn't a duplicate by now.

Answer (score 1):

--- Edited when comment was made that the ../ was still in the path ---

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("../../home");
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

will run with the output

```
/home/ebuck/home
/home/ebuck/workspace/State/../../home
```

based on my current working directory of `/home/ebuck/workspace/State`

Note that you asked for the complete real file path, which technically an absolute path is a complete, real file path, it's just not the shortest complete real file path.  So, if you want to do it fast and dirty, one can just add "../../home" to the current working directory and obtain a full, complete file path (albeit a wordy one that contains unnecessary information).

If you want the *shortest* full, complete file path, that's what `getCanonicalPath()` is used for.  It throws an exception; because, some joker out there will probably ask for "../../home" when in the root directory.

--- Original post follows, with edits ---

```
new File("../../dir/file.ext").getCanonoicalPath();
```

Will do so collapsing (following) the relative path links (`.` and `..`).

```
new File("../../dir/file.ext").getAbsolutePath();
```

Will do so without collapsing (following) the relative path links.

Comment: You want `getCanonicalPath()` to actually remove the "../" from the path. `getAbsolutePath()` simply returns it with the "../" in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = new File("../../dir/file.ext").getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever "tied" down to the second on a response before. :-O

Comment: this will not replace the ../ parts of the file path

Comment: Changed to `getCanonicalPath()` as probably desired. Does appear that the `..` can be preserved otherwise.

Comment: @WhiteFang32, You're 100% on that.  Absolute path returns just that (and absolute path, no matter how convoluted) while canonical attempts to return the shortest (best) path.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("..");
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes File.getCanonicalPath() may not be desired since it may resolve things like symlinks, so if you want to maintain the "logical" path that File.getAbsolutePath() provides, you cannot use getCanonicalPath().  Also, IIRC, gCP() can thrown an exception while gAP() does not, and gAP() can refer to a path does not exist.

I've encounter the '..' problem a long time ago.  Here is a utility method I wrote to remove the '..'s in a path:

```
  /**
   * Retrieve "clean" absolute path of a file.
   * <p>This method retrieves the absolute pathname of file,
   * with relative components (e.g. <tt>..</tt>) removed.
   * Java's <tt>File.getAbsolutePath()</tt> does not remove
   * relative components.  For example, if given the pathname:
   * </p>
   * <pre>
   * dir/subdir/subsubdir/../../file.txt
   * </pre>
   * <p>{@link File#getAbsolutePath()} will return something like:
   * </p>
   * <pre>
   * /home/whomever/dir/subdir/subsubdir/../../file.txt
   * </pre>
   * <p>This method will return:
   * </p>
   * <pre>
   * /home/whomever/dir/file.txt
   * </pre>
   *
   * @param   f       File to get clean absolute path of.
   * @return  Clean absolute pathname of <i>f</i>.
   */
  public static String cleanAbsolutePath(
      File f
  ) {
    String abs = f.getAbsolutePath();
    if (!relDirPattern.matcher(abs).find()) {
      // Nothing to do, so just return what Java provided
      return abs;
    }
    String[] parts = abs.split(fileSepRex);
    ArrayList<String> newPath = new ArrayList<String>(parts.length);
    int capacity = 0;
    for (String p : parts) {
      if (p.equals(".")) continue;
      if (p.equals("..")) {
    if (newPath.size() == 0) continue;
    String removed = newPath.remove(newPath.size() -1);
    capacity -= removed.length();
    continue;
      }
      newPath.add(p);
      capacity += p.length();
    }

    int size = newPath.size();
    if (size == 0) {
      return File.separator;
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(capacity);
    int i = 0;
    for (String p : newPath) {
      ++i;
      result.append(p);
      if (i < size) {
    result.append(File.separatorChar);
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  /** Regex string representing file name separator. */
  private static String fileSepRex     = "\\"+File.separator;
  /** Pattern for checking if pathname has relative components. */
  private static Pattern relDirPattern = Pattern.compile(
      "(?:\\A|" + fileSepRex + ")\\.{1,2}(?:" + fileSepRex + "|\\z)");
```